# Angular.js обновление данных

Tags: javascript, angularjs, обновление

Не могу разобраться как сделать динамическое обновление данных. Допустим есть массив объектов `users`, и хочется раз в секунду с помощью `$http.get()` получать данные об этих пользователях. Если бы не асинхронность, то это выглядело бы примерно так:

```
var users = [];
setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        $http.get('/user/'+i).then(function (res) {
            users[i] = res.data;
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```

Но когда в дело вступает асинхронность, `i` естественно уже не равна тому чему надо.
Сделать функцию `users[i].update(data)`, которая бы через `this` данного объекта присваивала новые данные тоже не удалось - теряется контекст `this` (он становится равным `window`)

**UPDATE**
Нашел решение, но оно больше похоже на костыль:

```
var users = [];
setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        $http.get('/user/'+i).success((function (object) {
            return function (data) {
                for (var key in data) {
                    object[key] = data[key];
                }
            }
        })(users[i]));
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: если в вашем решении захватывать только `i`  - оно будет выглядеть лучше :)

Comment: Никогда не используйте для переодических запросов setInterval !, иначе перекрытие вам обеспечено в какой то момент. Следующий запрос делайте только по завершении всех предыдущий, для этого можно использовать jquery.deferred. (к тому же он проксируется сервисом $q)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `query()` сервиса `$resource` из модуля `ngResource`, чтобы получить всех пользователей.

В `$http` вы можете использовать `headers` и `config`, чтобы как-то пометить запрос на получение пользователей.

Comment: Пытался заменить `$http.get()` сделав `$resource('/user/:id')`, и в цикле каждый раз делать `users[i] = get({id: i})`, работает с одним НО: пока не пришли данные, ничего не отображается. Соответственно, значения из вида пропадают на время получения данных (пока обещание не разрешится)

Comment: @Disminder, после параметров в функциях `$resource` можно задать обработчики success и error, в которых и присваивать

Comment: @Grundy, опять таки, потеря контекста - `this` начинает указывать на глобальный объект, переменная итератора так же теряется.

Comment: @Disminder, а зачем вам `this`? вы его ни в одной функции не используете

Comment: @Grundy, тут код ведь только для примера, реально система сложнее. Если в данном случае - то как обработчик (success например) узнает в какой объект ему нужно вставить пришедшие данные? Можно было бы каждому объекту массива добавить метод `update`, который бы принимал новые данные и добавлял их как раз через `this`, и вызывать данный метод как `success` но, как я уже сказал, `this` теряет контекст.

Comment: @Disminder, в двух словах это выглядит так: вы придумываете себе трудности, а потом героически их преодолеваете. единственное что вам надо сделать - сохранить(замкнуть) `i` чтобы использовать его при вставке.

Comment: @Grundy, фактически вы правы, поэтому весь вопрос в том, как это сделать наименее костыльно, если других путей решения нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35935/discussion-between-grundy-and-disminder).